# Is there a `tail` line length limit?

Tags: bash, tail

I have two files each containing two lines (https://gist.github.com/pcantalupo/2c06398f89c349ba9ee21059dad2d4fe)

When I run `tail -n1` on each and check number of lines with `wc`, I was suprised to see that the 2nd file containing a line with 8191 characters (well 8192 bytes including the newline) gives an unexpected result.

```
$ tail -n1 foo8190.fa | wc -l
       1
$ tail -n1 foo8191.fa | wc -l
       2
```

Is there a `tail` line length limit? bash limit?

Comment: POSIX does not require tools to handle lines longer than `LINE_MAX` bytes, a system dependent constant with a minimum value of 2048.

Comment: Which OS you are using?  It's working for me on `ubunutu 18.04.2` Demo : `$tail -n1 file.txt |  wc -c 
8192
$tail -n1 file.txt |  wc -l
1
`